# How can I restore deleted Folders from /etc?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, mysql

I tried to connect django to a mariadb for several hours.

I thought it was a good idea to delete the /etc/mysql folder, because I thought it was installed through a none-working package.

I think that was a mistake.

I cant install `mariadb-server` now because of the missing folder.

What can I do???

Comment: What error apt gives you when you try to install this package?

Comment: Restoring from your backups would be first & easiest. If you know the missing file(s), you can work out the packages that installed them, and re-install them (you may only need to re-run the *post-installation* script but check the package for details). Backups are easiest, so start restoring.  As already stated, providing the error message lets us help you with that.